# What is the difference between gVim and gVim easy?

Tags: vim

The question is self explanatory, but I haven't found a single resource that explains what the difference is after an hour of searching. After poking around a little bit in both, it appears that gVim and gVim easy are identical.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall - Why was this post edited?

Comment: Plus Andrew gets a lot of easy points for those who do not post like robots.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

gVim Easy is started and locked in insert-mode (every character you type is printed like a simple notepad).

Standard gVim starts in normal mode and you have to toggle between normal/insert like all other vim.

From help:

```
    Easy mode.  Implied for |evim| and |eview|.  Starts with
    'insertmode' set and behaves like a click-and-type editor.
    This sources the script $VIMRUNTIME/evim.vim.  Mappings are
    set up to work like most click-and-type editors, see
    |evim-keys|.  The GUI is started when available.
    {not in Vi}
```

Answer (score 2):

> gVim-Easy, which is installed with gVim, has all the functionality of
>   normal gVim but lacks modes. This is especially useful for begginers
>   and people who do not want to, or do not have the time to, learn how
>   to use gVim. Users can benefit from gVim's superior syntax
>   highlighting and auto-indentation while not having to have to learn
>   the, often deemed complex, command set of gVim in order to edit a
>   simple document. It is recommended that readers of this tutorial at
>   least try to learn how to use gVim in normal mode, the learning curve
>   is steep, but, the benefits in speed and usability this confers is
>   worth the investment.

Read [here](http://supportweb.cs.bham.ac.uk/documentation/tutorials/docsystem/build/tutorials/gvim/gvim.html#gVim-Installation-EasygVim)

Comment: “has all the functionality of normal gVim but lacks modes” False, there is no way to remove modes from vim. Gvim-easy is just the same as Gvim except for the fact that it does additional initialization listed in help (see @Tim quote): sources one script.

Answer (score 1):

- gVim Easy: `gvim.exe -y`  (pass a parameter `y`)
- gVim: `gvim.exe`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Insert and Replace are available modes, and command mode is missing.  And at first glance it appears to have lost the ability to save a document using keystrokes - the File menu shows only ":w" for Save and without command mode, the command simply isn't there.  What isn't shown however is Alt-F followed by S - this works, although also missing is the status line confirmation of the file being written.

Answer (score 0):

So gVim Easy seems to be just gVim locked in insert mode. However, as found on [super**user**](https://superuser.com/questions/353776/executing-commands-in-gvim-easy), Ctrl-L puts you back into command mode.