# How to exit from "vim -y" in console?

Tags: linux, vim

Accidentally I typed `vim -y install python-requests` instead of `yum ...` and I do not know how to exit from vim now. Standard option with `shift + : + q!` does not work. Are there any options how to exit from vim without killing it?

Comment: Easy mode is not easy

Comment: So use ctrl+q to quit easy mode, and never open it again

Answer (score 37, accepted):

With `-y` (easy mode), Vim defaults to *insert mode*, and you cannot permanently exit to *normal mode* via `<Esc>`. However, like in default Vim, you can issue a single normal mode command via `<C-O>`. So to exit, type `<C-O>:q!<CR>`.

Alternatively, there's a special `<C-L>` mapping for easy mode that returns to normal mode.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget: First rule is "Don't panic". Then, remember that Vim has excellent documentation.

Comment: `set noinsertmode` (needs C-o as prefix in easy mode) will bring normal mode back, although it cannot revert all changes loaded in easy mode (see evim.vim in vim runtime directory)

Comment: But this doesn't make sense to have this as default way of quitting easy mode, as it is made specifically for people who don't know vim's "model editing"... hence ctrl-q

Answer (score 16):

`-y` option makes vim start in easy mode, you can type CTRL-L to return to normal mode and then type :q! to exit.

Answer (score 1):

I use the *gVim Easy*, and it works for me to add the `set im!` in the `.gvimrc`.

[gVim Easy v.s. gVim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251496/what-is-the-difference-between-gvim-and-gvim-easy)

Answer (score 1):

It's good to remember that `vim` and `vim -y` (gVim Easy) are almost identical except for these differences:

- `vim` starts out in NORMAL mode; `vim -y` starts out in INSERT mode.
- <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-[</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> exit INSERT mode in `vim`.  However, these do not work in `vim -y`.  Instead, these have been replaced with <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd>.
- <kbd>Ctrl-Q</kbd> allows the user to quit `vim -y` with a **Save** prompt.  (However, saving your file will only work if you specified the filename at the prompt, or previously saved it off with *non-easy* `vim` command.)
- <kbd>Ctrl-S</kbd> will save your current file in `vim -y`.  (But just like with <kbd>Ctrl-Q</kbd>, saving your file will only work if you specified the filename at the prompt, or previously saved it off with *non-easy* `vim` command.  Otherwise, you'll get a `No file name` error.)

And it's good to remember this important similarity as well:

In INSERT mode, both `vim` and `vim -y` will allow you to use the <kbd>Ctrl-</kbd> commands that work during INSERT mode.  Examples include:

- <kbd>Ctrl-T</kbd> to indent the current line.
- <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> to dedent (that is, un-indent) the current line.
- <kbd>Ctrl-N</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd> to auto-complete the word currently being typed.
- <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> to paste the contents of register `x` where the cursor is.

and, relevant to this thread:

- <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> to temporarily enter NORMAL mode to issue one NORMAL-mode command (after which you'll immediately return to INSERT mode).

Hopefully you'll see that this last one (the <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> command) will allow you to save (with `:w`), save-and-quit (with `:wq`), discard unsaved changes (with `:e!`), as well as simply quit-without-saving (with `:q!`).

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> followed by a non-ex command, like `u` (for "undo"), `dd` (to delete the current line), `ZZ` (to save-and-quit), and `ZQ` (to quit-without-saving).

So if you're not familiar with using <kbd>Ctrl-</kbd> commands in vim's INSERT mode, I strongly recommend learning at least the <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> command, as remembering that will help you figure out how to exit (and save documents in) `vim -y`.  (While knowledge of <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd> will help with `vim -y`, knowledge of <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> will help in *both* `vim -y` and `vim`.)

---

**Key Takeaways**

If there are only three things you remember from this post, remember these:

1. <kbd>Ctrl-Q</kbd> is the simple and straightforward way to exit `vim -y`, but you won't be able to save your file if you haven't previously specified a filename for it.
2. `vim`'s normal way of exiting INSERT mode (that is, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-[</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>) have been replaced with <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd> in `vim -y` (Vim Easy).
3. The INSERT mode command of <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> works just as well in `vim -y` (Vim Easy) as it does in `vim`.  So you can use it to your advantage to execute any NORMAL commands you want.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> is used to quit easy mode.

Comment: This is excellent!  I can't believe I never knew about this before!

Comment: no, it's not used to quit easy mode.  
ctrl+q is simply a shortcut in some desktop environments, so if you don't have one (no GUI, only CLI) it won't work, and it doesn't have any relation to vim.

Comment: No.. it works in tty(just to make sure i tried it). you might have some configuration overriding ctrl-q mapping, try running vim without configs `vim -y -u NONE`